# How to return a value in the only non-blank column in a range for sendEmail function in Google App Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The issue is: I can't find a way to return the value for 'Course' because each form submission generates a new row where the name of the course is spread over columns E to M (column 4 through 12).

In each row, there is only one 'Course' name in one of the columns from E to M (e.g only in F) and all other columns are blank. (Users can only select one course and all the other columns will be blank. I have to categorize the courses into the 9 columns because of the page breaks in order to split the sheer number of options that users select the course from.) How do I return the value of the only non blank cell from E to M which will be entered in the email ?

I was advised to insert the entire findCourse function inside of the sendEmail function before any of the other code. I did so but I have still been receiving failure notifications of the Google App Scripts: `TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 14, file "Code")` (referring to var value = e.values[i])

The full code below:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
function findCourse (e){
      var courseToTake;
      //loop through values 
      for ( var i = 4; i <=12; i ++){
           //pull value into variable 
           var value = e.values[i]; 
         if (value != undefined){
               //if we find an actual string value, set the course to take variable 
               courseToTake = value; 
            }
     }
    return courseToTake; 
}

var Name = e.namedValues["Full name as appear in NRIC"];
var Course = findCourse();
var Start = e.values[14];
var End = e.values[15];
var StartTime = e.values[24];
var EndTime = e.values[25];
var Details = e.values[13];
var Cost = e.values[17];
var Email = e.values[18];
var ROname = e.values[19];
var ROemail = e.values[20];
var Location = e.values[23];
var subject = "Training Approval Request for " + Course;
var message = "<p >" + "Dear " + ROname + "<p />"
+ Name + " seeks your approval to attend the " + Course + ". The details are as follow:"
+ "<p >" + "<b>Date:</b> " + Start + " - " + End + " <br />"
+ "<b>Time:</b> " + StartTime + " - " + EndTime + " <br />"
+ "<b>Location:</b> " + Location + " <br />"
+ "<b>Course objectives and benefits:</b> " + Details + " <br />"
+ "<b>Course fees:</b> " + "$" + Cost + " <br />" + "<p />" 
+ "Please reply directly to this email for your approval or if you have any questions/comments. Thank you. "


MailApp.sendEmail(ROemail, Email, subject, message);
}
```

After rearranging findCourse as its own function: sorry if I made any mistakes here but i'll try my best to follow all suggestions. If i've added in Logger.log(e) correctly, both functions seem to be undefined

```
function sendEmail(e) {

 Logger.log(e);



var Name = e.values[2];
var Course = findCourse();
var Start = e.values[14];
var End = e.values[15];
var StartTime = e.values[24];
var EndTime = e.values[25];
var Details = e.values[13];
var Cost = e.values[17];
var Email = e.values[18];
var ROname = e.values[19];
var ROemail = e.values[20];
var Location = e.values[23];
var subject = "Training Approval Request for " + Course;
var message = "<p >" + "Dear " + ROname + "<p />"
+ Name + " seeks your approval to attend the " + Course + ". The details are as follow:"
+ "<p >" + "<b>Date:</b> " + Start + " - " + End + " <br />"
+ "<b>Time:</b> " + StartTime + " - " + EndTime + " <br />"
+ "<b>Location:</b> " + Location + " <br />"
+ "<b>Course objectives and benefits:</b> " + Details + " <br />"
+ "<b>Course fees:</b> " + "$" + Cost + " <br />" + "<p />" 
+ "Please reply directly to this email for your approval or if you have any questions/comments. Thank you. "


MailApp.sendEmail(ROemail, Email, subject, message);
}

 function findCourse (e){

  var courseToTake; 

  //loop through values 

  for ( var i = 4; i <=12; i ++){

       //pull value into variable 

       var value = e.values[i]; 



     if (value != undefined){

           //if we find an actual string value, set the course to take variable 

           courseToTake = value; 

        }

 }




  return courseToTake; 

 var courseToTake = findCourse(e);

Logger.log(e);

}
```

I will really deeply appreciate any help or alternative solutions here.

Thank you!

Comment: 'e' is most likely undefined because there is no argument passed into the `findCourse()` function. What calls this function, can you post the rest of you code?

Comment: This is the full code:
 function sendEmail(e) { 
  
  function findCourse (e){

      var courseToTake; 

      //loop through values 

      for ( var i = 4; i <=12; i ++){

           //pull value into variable 

           var value = e.values[i]; 

           

         if (value != undefined){

               //if we find an actual string value, set the course to take variable 

               courseToTake = value; 

            }

     }
    return courseToTake; 



}

Comment: Can you post this code into your post, formatted? It's a pain to copy/paste non-formatted code, especially when it contains comments.

Comment: Assuming `sendEmail` is called on form submit, remove the `findCourse` function from within the `sendEmail` function and make a call to `findCourse`, passing in `e` as an object. Also add a `Logger.log(e)` in yor `sendEmail` function before you call `findCourse` and check the logs to see if `e` is defined there, also log `e` inside of `findcourse`. Reply back with your findings

Comment: Yepp sendEmail is called on with the form submit trigger. Sorry could I clarify what you mean to call findCourse, passing in e as an object?

Comment: Move `findCourse` out of `sendEmail` as it's own function, and call it like: `var courseToTake = findCourse(e);`

Comment: Not sure if I understood your suggestions correctly but I've added in the edited code in my post. Im sharing the link to the spreadsheet with view and edit access to the form and script if it helps give a bigger picture. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CqTFevzicxXMpbX9b9Ax7yVLkK_v-iYmhDd8HrRlX3A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I changed in your code to address your question:

- I assigned the `onFormSubmit` trigger to your `sendEmail` function so the event object would no longer be undefined
- I added a call to `findCourse()` so your `course` variable would no longer be undefined
- I fixed the undefined check by changing `if(value != undefined)` to `if(typeof value !== 'undefined')`
- I added a check for a blank value (This was the important bit in the logic after the faulty undefined check) `if(value != '')`

Explanation:

To trigger the event, an installable trigger needs to be setup for the `On Form Submit` event that points to your `sendEmail` function. This can be found in `Resources -> Current Project Triggers`

To retrieve the course, you need to call your function `findCourse()` and pass in the `e` event object. Example: `var course = findCourse(e);`. This will assign the return value from `findCourse(e);` to the `course` variable. You can then use this variable like normal within the rest of your statements.

When checking for `undefined`, you need to use `typeof` and then check for the string of `'undefined'`, or your check will ironically throw an undefined exception.

The values of the form submit should not be `undefined`, blank values should just be blank strings. so checking for non-blank strings was necessary to get the course name from the values array.

Fixed Code:

```
function sendEmail(e) {

 Logger.log(e) 


  var course = findCourse(e);

  var Name = e.values[19];
  var Start = e.values[12];
  var End = e.values[14];
  var StartTime = e.values[13];
  var EndTime = e.values[15];
  var Details = e.values[11];
  var Cost = e.values[17];
  var Email = e.values[20];
  var ROname = e.values[21];
  var ROemail = e.values[22];
  var Location = e.values[16];
  var subject = "Training Approval Request for " + course;
  var message = "<p >" + "Dear " + ROname + "<p />"
  + Name + " seeks your approval to attend the " + course + ". The details are as follow:"
  + "<p >" + "<b>Date:</b> " + Start + " - " + End + " <br />"
  + "<b>Time:</b> " + StartTime + " - " + EndTime + " <br />"
  + "<b>Location:</b> " + Location + " <br />"
  + "<b>Course objectives and benefits:</b> " + Details + " <br />"
  + "<b>Course fees:</b> " + "$" + Cost + " <br />" + "<p />" 
  + "Please reply directly to this email for your approval or if you have any questions/comments. Thank you. "

  MailApp.sendEmail(ROemail, Email+";" + "redactedEmail", subject, message);
}

function findCourse (e){
  var courseToTake; 

  //loop through values 
  for ( var i = 2; i <=10; i ++){   
    //pull value into variable 
    var value = e.values[i];             
    if (typeof value !== 'undefined'){ //If value is defined
      if(value != ''){ //If value is not blank
        //if we find an actual non-blank string value, set the course to take variable       
        courseToTake = value;           
      }   
    }   
  }  
  return courseToTake; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for fixing it with these explanations, Douglas!